# what does .svg('get') mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I have seen this syntax in many places, but cannot find any explanation on internet what does this two lines do, could anyone explain it?

```
$('#svgContainer').svg();           
var svg = $('#svgContainer').svg('get');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a plugin for jQuery that creates (first line) and then returns (second line) a [SVG element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). Possibly [this one](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)?

From that plugin's documentation (found by clicking on 'Quick Ref'):

```
$(selector).svg('get') // Retrieve SVG wrapper
```

Comment: Are you looking for a more in depth description of SVG or the plug in?